# How does MetaCPAN handle pod generation?

Tags: metacpan

I recently uploaded a new distribution to MetaCPAN and it choose the POD in my `pod/` directory to render as the index for the documentation for the distribution.

How does it decide this?

What is the order that it looks for pod to render the index?